# Elliptic Curve Cryptography with Python on Windows

Tags: python, elliptic-curve, encryption-asymmetric

I'm looking for a way to generate keys for asymmetric cryptograpy via elliptic curves in Python, but all packages I was able to find only support UNIX systems. Anyone know a package that works on Windows?

Comment: Better to ask at [Software recommendations.SE](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)?